# Show 200+ fields on Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, custom-field

I am working on requirement to display more than 200-300 fields on a custom object in a lightning component.

Since I dont want to display all fields the fields I want to display them conditionally only when the fields are populated.

The fields are structured in such a way that they are grouped into sets
Field 1 - Name, Order,Desc - 4 custom fields
Field 2 - Name2,order2,Desc2 - 4 custom fields

What I want to do is create field sets for all the common groups and loop through the fields sets to check if the fields are null and display them.

Also as a Plan B I have created a child object where I have created these common fields and creating records after inserting parent records. This is a huge data duplication approach I was taking to work as a fail-safe.

Happy to hear any suggestions from the community on this.

Comment: 200-300 is way too many fields. If you have 60 fields, the Salesforce Optimizer will already complain: "Excessive fields clutter your page layouts, make your implementation difficult to maintain, and increase page load time." Human beings cannot cope with so many fields, it is information overload.

Comment: Thank you, I cascaded the recurring fields in a child object and reduced the count of fields to less than 50.